# how to pass table names and columns as arguments plsql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

This is my first post on stack overflow so please lmk if my question been asked incorrectly.

I am trying to make a procedure in plsql (which I've only been using for the last couple weeks) that is passed two arguments: a column name and its associated table. This procedure is then called in Oracle APEX which in turn creates a [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) with the column name as the header of the table with populated rows.

I have gotten this procedure to work statically with predefined values for the column name and table name, but I want it to be dynamic as this procedure will be used in other places. Here is my current attempt:

```
procedure dataTable(column_name VARCHAR2, table_name VARCHAR2) as

   select_sql varchar2(1024);
   --this should be a record or cursor i think, but I'm not sure how to do either
   result_sql varchar2(1024);


begin
     htp.p('<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="some_id"String cellspacing="0"String><thead><tr>');
     htp.p('<th>'||column_name||'</th>');
     htp.p('</tr></thead><tbody>');         
     select_sql := 'SELECT ' ||column_name||' FROM '||table_name;
     --error occurs on line below
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE select_sql into result_sql;
     for i in result_sql LOOP
         htp.p('<tr><td>'||i.(something here to access row data)||'</td></tr>');
     end loop;   
end;
```

This gives the error:

Compilation failed,line 40 (13:52:44)
PLS-00456: item 'RESULT_SQL' is not a cursorCompilation failed,line 40 (13:52:44)
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I have looked in the [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011) about dynamic plsql and records/cursors and have attempted the examples to no avail.

Any suggestions on what to do to? Thanks.

EDIT: Fixed minor errors

Comment: Which line corresponds with the error? Currently, there is no line 40 that we can see.

Comment: Also, try changing  the `EXECUTE` line into: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '' || select_sql || ' into ' || result_sql;` and tell us what happens.

Comment: Using just the answer below by @GurV I was getting another error, and by adding that I have no more errors. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a PLSQL table to hold the values of the result of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` using *`BULK COLLECT`*

```
procedure dataTable(column_name VARCHAR2, table_name VARCHAR2) as
    select_sql varchar2(1024);

    type sometype IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(1024) index by PLS_INTEGER;
    result sometype;

begin
    htp.p('<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="some_id"String cellspacing="0"String><thead><tr>');
    htp.p('<th>'||column_name||'</th>');
    htp.p('</tr></thead><tbody>');         
    select_sql := 'SELECT ' ||column_name||' FROM '||table_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE select_sql into result;
    IF result.count > 0 THEN
        FOR i IN result.first .. result.last LOOP
            htp.p('<tr><td>'||result(i)||'</td></tr>');
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: solved the issue and now compiles in the sql workshop, but I am now getting compile errors in APEX on the webpage at the line with new execute immediate statement suggested by @Mooz

`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: yeah figured that out, all is working now after changing a couple things